# Dialogflow fullfilment code send otp using twilio in nodejs

Tags: node.js, twilio

I want to send otp to my mobile number, as part of a fulfilment on dialogflow using twilio. I have followed the instructions in https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-send-sms-messages-node-js link to setup twilio account and get the phone number. Have added the account sid and authtoken also in the code.But still I am not able to recieve any sms in my mobile. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code which I have as part of OTP authentication.

```
 app.intent('Proceed_Auth', (conv) => {
  client.messages.create({
      body: `You just sent an SMS from Node.js using Twilio!`,
      from: '+1619XXXXXXX',
      to: '+9194XXXXXXXX'
    }).then(
        (message) => console.log("send msg",message.sid)
        );
    conv.contexts.set('otp', 1);
    conv.ask('I have sent an OTP to your number. Please enter the OTP');
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that once the intent is finished with the last call to `conv` that the intent is closed? Since sending a message is asynchronous, the function might be closed down before it is complete. Try making the calls to `conv` in the `then` function.

Comment: I have tried that. But still no use :-(

Comment: Where is `client` defined as part of this intent? Are you able to send a message with Twilio outside of this context, with just the code from the documentation that you followed? Do you get any logs or messages as part of this intent?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have defined client at the beginning with the authtoken and account id.                                                                          
const client = require('twilio')(
  'ACxxxxxx..',
  '4cxxxxx.....'
);           Also the exact same piece of code is working when I have used in microsoft bot framework (using node js).

Comment: Have you tried defining the client from within the intent? It may work as part of bot framework, but I imagine that each framework like this will treat your code differently. Perhaps the code that is outside of the intent doesn't run every time, for example. So try defining the client inside the intent and let me know how that goes.

Comment: yes I have tried that. But same problem

Comment: Are there any logs or error messages that might help?

Comment: No error message was printing. Even this console.log("send msg",message.sid)  one also not printing. It is directly executing conv.ask('I have sent an OTP to your number. Please enter the OTP');

Comment: It might be best to update your question with your latest code that you are using. Let me know and I'll take another look.